# how to bind data to grid in a user control in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have a user control,lets say usercontrol1 and i add a datagridview control to that user control for reusability. but i can't bind data to that datagrid from a datatable. how can i do this data binding to grid from datatable.can you suggest any method.

Comment: don't understand the question. why can't you bind the data?

Answer (score 1):

In your CS file CReate a method called bind grid something like this.

```
protected void Bindgrid(DataTable dt)
{
   if (dt != null)
   { 
     if (dt.rows.count > 0)
     {
         gvYourGrid.DataSource = dt;
         gvYourGrid.DataBind();
     }
   }
}
```

Now whenever you want to bind just pass the datatable to that method. And also do allow auto generate columns to true.

Comment: @Jithin and @Amit, I've done similar things having a user control have more than just a grid... a header description label, buttons like to print or apply filtering criteria, etc based on dynamic grid content.  Having this public method to apply binding to the grid works well.

Comment: how can we call the datagrid control in userontrol from winform ??